# Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a "master" process that needs to spawn some child processes.

How can I manage these child processes? (for example, restart if the process is dead)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Comment: You are a god among men. Thanks for saving me a weekend.

Comment: @Jordan, that is the best comment ever posted to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the multiprocessing package, every child process has `is_alive` method you can check. So one option to to hold a list of all running processes and periodically check `is_alive` and re-spawn dead processes.

If you're on POSIX system, you can also catch SIGCHLD (using `signal`) and get notified when a child process dies.

Answer (score 1):

This will help http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

edit : a good tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/