# python process wrapper

Tags: python, process

I need to write a process wrapper in python that will launch an application and restart it if it fails. This will be logged to an specified log location passed in from command line. Is this possible?

Comment: Describe fail. Some error on stderr? return code?

Comment: Advice: Search.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=python%20process%20restart%20  The following may answer your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850708/python-multiprocessing.  If it's not appropriate, please provide some details so we know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> def spawner(cmd_list):
...     while True:
...         print "Running proc..."
...         mon_proc = Popen(cmd_list)
...         print "Proc exit: %s" % mon_proc.wait()
... 
>>> spawner(['/bin/sleep', '3'])
Running proc...
Proc exit: 0
Running proc...
Proc exit: 0
Running proc...
Proc exit: 0
Running proc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. Use Popen to start it and get a Popen objet. Use Popen.poll() or wait to get process status depending of what you want. Do it in a loop, and log using the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.

my 2 cents